# Tailwind CSS Doesn't Display In Production On Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-6, tailwind-css

I integrated Tailwind CSS into my Rails 6 App. The CSS is displayed fine in development but that isn't the case in production.

This is how my `application.html.erb` looks like;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HomePetVet</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% unless flash.empty? %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        <% flash.each do |f| %>
          <% type = f[0].to_s.gsub('alert', 'error').gsub('notice', 'info') %>
          toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= f[1] %>');
        <% end %>
      </script>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'sb-admin-2', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my `webpacker.yml` file;

```
 production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

I seet `extract_css` to `true` in `webpacker.yml`

This is my `package.json` file;

```
 {
  "name": "MyProject",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

You can observe that `tailwindcss` is not under `devDependencies`.
Before deploying to `gcp` by `gcloud app deploy` I do `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` but the `tailwind css` is still not showing in production.

I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine) to deploy my Rails 6 App to GCP.

This is my `app.yaml` file:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT
runtime: ruby
env: flex

manual_scaling:
 instances: 1
resources:
 cpu: 1
 memory_gb: 0.5
 disk_size_gb: 10
```

Notice `entrypoint: bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT` in `app.yaml`. The one from the guide is `entrypoint: bundle exec rackup --port $PORT`

I don't know if this makes a difference but I wanted to mention it.

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to describe more information regarding the deployment into your production environment? What GCP documentation was followed? I would like to invite you to post the issue onto the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to provide more details regarding your issue.

Comment: @JanL I have updated the question with the link to the guide I followed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase, another Dev comes across this issue, this is how I solved it;

I edited the `postcss.config.js` file to include `require('autoprefixer')`

```
    let environment = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer'), #added this
        require('tailwindcss')('./app/javascript/stylesheets/tailwind.config.js'),
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
        require('postcss-preset-env')({
            autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009'
            },
            stage: 3
        })
    ]
};
module.exports = environment;
```

With this, `Tailwind CSS` is showing in production on GCP.

Comment: I'm not sure how general this solution is, as I have a new RoR project with the tailwindcss-rails gem, yet I have no postcss.config.js file.

Comment: @LelandReardon, it has been a while since I've worked with the Google Cloud Platform.
However, consider the Rails version you're using. 
There is now official tailwind CSS support for Rails v7+: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails